# Move constructor for ICU's string

Tags: c++, icu

I've written a wrapper class for the ICU string, and I've got a move-aware compiler, but ICU does not provide a move constructor. I was also unable to find a swap() function I could use to perform this job. How can I implement move semantics for an ICU string?

Comment: I suppose overloading/specializing `std::move` for `icu::string` won't cut it? EDIT: ICU is open source, right? Why not just patch the class to have a move constructor?

Comment: @rubenvb `std::move` only works at the type level. It simply changes the value category of the argument to rvalue. Other than that, it's an identity function.

Comment: @rubenvb You meant patch the source and then contribute the patch, right?

Comment: @StevenR.Loomis Obviously :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're okay with the overhead of a pointer dereference every time you access the string(I wouldn't be), you can always store the icu string in a `std::unique_ptr`, then moving is as simple as moving the pointer.

```
MyWrapper(MyWrapper && that)
    :str_ptr(std::move(that.str_ptr))
{}
```

Personally, I would feel better about actually modifying the ICU source.

Comment: I thought I saw a ticket on this, but I can't find it.

Comment: ticket is at http://www.icu-project.org/trac/ticket/10086 with a related one at http://www.icu-project.org/trac/ticket/8324